# How to join two Spark Structured Streams?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

Is it possible to join two Spark Structured Streams in Spark 2.2.1? I found a lot of issues with doing very simple manipulations in Spark Structured Streaming. The documentation and number of examples seem very limited to me. 
I have two sources of streaming data:

persons.json:

```
[
  {"building_id": 70, "id": 21, "latitude": 41.20, "longitude": 2.2, "timestamp": 1532609003},
  {"building_id": 70, "id": 15, "latitude": 41.24, "longitude": 2.3, "timestamp": 1532609005},
  {"building_id": 71, "id": 11, "latitude": 41.28, "longitude": 2.1, "timestamp": 1532609005}
]
```

machines.json

```
[
  {"building_id": 70, "mid": 222, "latitude": 42.1, "longitude": 2.11}
]
```

The goal is to get a merged DataFrame with latitude and longitude of persons and machines. I need it in order to estimate the distance between them in real time:

```
building_id   id   mid   latitude  longitude  latitude_machine  longitude_machine
70            21   222   41.20     2.2        42.1              2.11
# ...
```

If it's impossible to join two streams, then I would really appreciate some recommendation of a possible workaround.

Code:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Test") \
    .master("local[2]") \
    .getOrCreate()

schema_persons = StructType([
    StructField("building_id", IntegerType()),
    StructField("id", IntegerType()),
    StructField("latitude", DoubleType()),
    StructField("longitude", DoubleType()),
    StructField("timestamp", LongType())
])

schema_machines = StructType([
    StructField("building_id", IntegerType()),
    StructField("mid", IntegerType()),
    StructField("latitude", DoubleType()),
    StructField("longitude", DoubleType())
])

df_persons = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("json") \
    .schema(schema_persons) \
    .load("data/persons")

df_machines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("json") \
    .schema(schema_machines) \
    .load("data/machines") \
    .withColumnRenamed("latitude", "latitude_machine") \
    .withColumnRenamed("longitude", "longitude_machine")

df_joined = df_persons\
              .join(df_machines, ["building_id"], "left")

query_persons = df_persons \
    .writeStream \
    .format('console') \
    .start()

query_machines = df_machines \
    .writeStream \
    .format('console') \
    .start()

query_persons.awaitTermination()
query_machines.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: In general stream-to-stream joins are supported in the latest versions (2.3, 2.4), but require watermark at least at on side - see the [join matrix](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#support-matrix-for-joins-in-streaming-queries). If you're looking for concrete examples [`StreamingJoinSuite`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingJoinSuite.scala) would be the place to go. In 2.2 however, joins between streaming datasets are not supported;

Comment: @user6910411: Thanks. But what is the workaround in Spark 2.2? Just nothing to do?

Comment: Other than upgrade? Not really.